# Block user from deleting files that will be uploaded to ftp

Tags: vb.net, ftp

i made a software that will upload files to an ftp and i want to those files when was chosen for upload cant be moved/deleted until the process is finished

my first try worked but i want more options

```
Dim block As New StreamReader("file location")
```

Comment: Need more information... what extra options do you need.... if I understand you correctly a user is uploading files from their file system via your ftp process to your system and you want to stop them deleting or moving those files until the process has finished... Is this correct. Is this a windows form app?

Comment: yes its windows form , i dont know if my current code is the proper way to do this

Comment: Could you post your working code and mention what options you are actually looking for?

Comment: I've not done this before but would look at doing something like change permission/owner of file before upload... The problem is that if the user is an administrator they would still be able to move delete. Another option is to make a copy of the files to a temporary location and then upload the copied files.

Comment: i have this code to capture drageed files into form  
Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)  
and this to loop into files()  
For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1  
Dim stopuser As New StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(files(i)))  
next

Comment: but to release them from that block i should close the program

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution
this code to block user from deleting or moving files while the files is transfering to the ftp

```
Dim stopuser As New StreamReader("file location")
```

and this code the release the files so the user can delete or move them

```
 Dim enableuser As New StreamReader("file location")
 enableuser.close()
```